# Passenger spawn server consume a lot of CPU

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, cpu

I'm using a VPS for testing (2Ghz, 512Mo RAM).
It's running Ubuntu 12.10 Server, Apache2, Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.12, Passenger 3.0.19.

The problem is that the process "Passenger spawn server" is constantly running at 50% of CPU.
(I'm the only user of my app.)
Is it normal? Can I do something?

More details :

passenger-status

```
----------- General information -----------
max      = 6
count    = 1
active   = 0
inactive = 1
Waiting on global queue: 0

----------- Application groups -----------
/home/foscam/www/ledu:
  App root: /home/foscam/www/ledu
  * PID: 31401   Sessions: 0    Processed: 10      Uptime: 3h 25m 24s
```

passenger-memory-stats

```
----- Passenger processes -----
PID    VMSize    Private  Name
-------------------------------
16207  215.7 MB  0.3 MB   PassengerWatchdog
16210  547.1 MB  0.8 MB   PassengerHelperAgent
16212  108.9 MB  6.2 MB   Passenger spawn server
16215  165.3 MB  1.0 MB   PassengerLoggingAgent
31401  246.4 MB  83.7 MB  Rack: /home/foscam/www/ledu
### Processes: 5
### Total private dirty RSS: 92.04 MB
```

Comment: Quite impossible to answer, but yes you could probably do something.